# Node.JS query MongoDB returning null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'am new to *Node.js* and *MongoDB* and I am trying it out.

I made a collection called `footIco`.
When I query *MongoDB* in the console with `db.footIco.find()`, it return all the data.

However when I query *MongoDB* from *Node.js* it doesn't return any data.

I can see the connection in *MongoDB* server console.

Here is my *Node.js* script;

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/footIco';

var findIco = function(db, callback) {
   var cursor =db.collection('footIco').find();
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      if (doc != null) {
         console.dir(doc);
      } else {
         callback();
           console.dir(doc);
      }
   });
};

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  findIco(db, function() {
      db.close();
  });
});
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this. It's pretty much a copy and paste from the *MongoDB* tutorial

Comment: Would help if I was using the good database name.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
assert.equal(err, null);
```

it is a JavaScript specific, that handlers that throws error will throw nowhere, I would recommend changing it to `console.log(err)` or just modify your callback to handle `err` parameter.

Comment: But I'm still getting no result event if I remove that part.

Comment: If you get no error and no data this means you have no data, did you check mongo instance with some mongo console like robomongo?

Comment: Yeah its working i was calling the wrong database. Thank you.